# How to place two image side by side into a div using bootstrap3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

i want to place two image side by side into a div where both images are center into parent div. i am using bootstrap 3. plz help

here is my markup:

```
    <div class="well text-center">
        <span>Sister Properties:</span>
            <a href="#"><img src="img/innlogo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="inn_logo" /></a> <a href="#" ><img src="img/cclogo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="ccs_logo" /></a>
    </div>
```

I cant do this using "row-column" div but i want to do it using "well" div.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `img-responsive` responsive class gives your images a `display:block` that prevents them from centering; try removing it. Also, in order for them to be placed side by side make use of Bootstrap's grid system. You can read more about it here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid.

Here is how you could do this:

```
<div class="well text-center">
    <span>Sister Properties:</span>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <a href="#"><img src="img/innlogo.png" alt="inn_logo" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <a href="#" ><img src="img/cclogo.png" alt="ccs_logo" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can play with it here: http://www.bootply.com/YSlrhJHBls

**EDIT**: To make the top text center add a 12 wide `col`. To ensure the images are inside the well too, wrap them inside a `div` with class `row` as follows:

```
<div class="well text-center">
    <div class="col-md-12">Sister Properties:</div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="inn_logo"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/" alt="ccs_logo"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the updated bootply: http://www.bootply.com/TuXAsykG7e

Comment: it's not working perfectly, in that case images are not fit into parent div ("well" div) and div title("sister properties") also not stay into center of the div. See this:

http://www.bootply.com/PZujGdrKlc

Comment: yep, i saw that, however that was not part of your question... let me see if i can get it working for you still...

Comment: it worked perfectly and i follow your first suggestion removing img-responsive responsive class solved the problem, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this on your css:

```
.well img{
display: inline-block;
}
```