# Align two images inline center of a bootstrap col

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I have a html template andi want to integrate bootstrap into it. I currently have two images in a bootstrap column. I want to keep the two images aligned and next to each other while cetnering both of them in the middle of the of the column. When I try it either doesnt center them or centers them on top of each other which I dont want. I want both images centered and next to each other... Here is my code:

```
  <div class="row justify-content-center">

        <div class="col-xl-6">
          <img class="welcome-icon-size align-top center-block" src="{% static 'images/untitled-2.png'%}" alt="Generic placeholder image">
          <img class="welcome-name-size no-margin-top center-block" src="{% static 'images/untitled-1.png'%}" alt="Generic placeholder image">
        </div>

  </div>
```

here is the css:

```
.no-margin-top {
  margin-top: 0px !important;
}

.no-padding {
  padding: 0em !important;
}

.welcome-icon-size {
  height: 9.55em !important;
}

.welcome-name-size {
  height: 14em !important;
}

.welcome_title {
  font-size: 1em !important
}

.welcome-center-items {
  align-items: center !important;
}

.center-block {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 }
```

here is what my image looks like:

[image]

I want it to look like the following but centered::

[image]

The images are not centered in the screenshot above they are aligned to the left of the column

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to place two image side by side into a div using bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26647890/how-to-place-two-image-side-by-side-into-a-div-using-bootstrap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is the css of align-top? I don't know what does this class do.
Try this:

- remove align-top and no-margin top classes from your images
- add class my-align or name it whatever you want (but in the css the class name should be the same - remember that)

and in the css it should look like:

```
.my-align { margin:0;padding:0;width:50%;float:left; }
```

is it what you want?

Comment: I added an image of what I want it to look like but have it centered in the middle of the row. please look at the post I have updated it

Comment: it kind worked. The one thing is that it is straching both images to fit the full width of the column. Is there any way that i can keep the image the same size it is and center it without straching the image.